# Difference $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on ExpressionEngine and PHP

Tags: ee2, server

I'm currently using the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable inside my config file.

In ExpressionEngine this is returned :

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devee
```

In PHP (no CMS) this is returned :

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

Is there a place, where ExpressionEngine is changing the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid using DOCUMENT_ROOT altogether, to avoid issues between servers. The doc root is specified in your apache config, and depending on your apache setup, isn't always guaranteed to give you the correct path to your root folder.

It's much more reliable to use `dirname(__FILE__)` (or `__DIR__` in PHP 5.3+) for the directory of the current script, and go from there. E.g. (in your `config.php` file):

```
$root = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../');
$config['theme_folder_path'] = $root.'themes/';
```

Comment: Much more flexible than document_root. Thanks you !

Answer (score 3):

I would assume ExpressionEngine is giving you the path to your system folder, since that is were the config.php file is located.

The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` provides:

> The document root directory under which the current script is
>   executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

It doesn't provide the base path to your html folder; it **provides** the path to the executing file/script.